# How to set default value in SubQuery result using mysql

Tags: mysql, database, default

How to set **default** VALUE in SubQuery result using mysql

```
SELECT      
    p.`id`, p.`name`, p.`class_name`, cpd.`status_team`,
    cpd.`home`, cpd.`guest`, cpd.`mvp`, cpd.`oscar`,
    cpd.`wam`, cpd.`status`, cpd.`added_date`,
    (SELECT result FROM result_cards WHERE `id` = cpd.`result`) AS DEFAULT(`result`)
FROM `cron_players_data` cpd
INNER JOIN `players` p ON cpd.`player_id` = p.id
WHERE cpd.`added_date` = '2012-03-29' AND cpd.team_id = '15'
```

when i remove this **DEFAULT()** the Query will execute normally. Actually i want by default **result** value is 0 or helps are definitely appreciated

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move the sub query to a join. But I am not able to understand what you are trying to do with DEFAULT(). You will need to explain what you are trying to achieve.

```
SELECT      
    p.`id`, p.`name`, p.`class_name`, cpd.`status_team`,
    cpd.`home`, cpd.`guest`, cpd.`mvp`, cpd.`oscar`,
    cpd.`wam`, cpd.`status`, cpd.`added_date`,
    IFNULL(rc.`result`, 0) AS `result`
FROM `cron_players_data` cpd
INNER JOIN `players` p
    ON cpd.`player_id` = p.id
LEFT JOIN result_cards rc
    ON cpd.`result` = rc.id
WHERE cpd.`added_date` = '2012-03-29'
AND cpd.team_id = '15'
```

Comment: Your Query has been worked or i found my answer with the help of your guidance thanx for sharing your experience

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you are trying to say. Did it work for you?

Comment: AFAIK you can only use DEFAULT in a SELECT context - [DEFAULT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_default). `SELECT DEFAULT(field) FROM tbl` or `UPDATE tbl SET field = DEFAULT(field)`

Comment: see my answer actually this thing i m trying to say

Comment: i got it what are you trying to say about default

Answer (score 7):

Solution IFNULL

```
SELECT      
p.`id`,p.`name`,p.`class_name`,cpd.`status_team`,cpd.`home`,cpd.`guest`,cpd.`mvp`,
cpd.`oscar`,cpd.`wam`,cpd.`status`,cpd.`added_date` ,
IFNULL((SELECT result FROM result_cards WHERE `id` = cpd.`result`),0) AS `result` 
FROM `cron_players_data` cpd INNER JOIN `players` p ON cpd.`player_id` = p.id
WHERE cpd.`added_date` = '2012-03-29' AND cpd.team_id = '15'
```

Comment: Why are you using the subquery instead of the left join? It does not make sense.

Comment: i just check this logic its work or not and i really thanks full to you

Comment: Up to you. I would advise against using a subquery in this context when a left join will produce the same result with much lower overhead.

Comment: @nnichols thanx for your advise and i already implemented your Query on my project

Comment: P E R F E C T! Thanks